# _InterlockedCompareExchange64 does not work properly when is defined

Tags: c++, compare, atomic, intrinsics, interlocked

Why the code below does not work correctly when `_InterlockedCompareExchange64`
is used as a define ? This instruction compares destination which is the 1st parameter with the 3rd parameter, and if they are equal, the 2nd parameter is copied back to the destination which is the 1st parameter.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"

#define ATOMIC_CAS(ptr, oldval, newval) _InterlockedCompareExchange64(ptr, newval, oldval)

int main()
{

    __int64 tt = 20;
    ATOMIC_CAS(&tt, 10, 20);
    //_InterlockedCompareExchange64(&tt, 10, 20);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the code that's commented out works correctly, then the problem is in the macro, which reverses the `oldval` and `newval` arguments. But it's impossible to say what the actual problem is, because this code snippet doesn't produce any output and the question doesn't say what the expected result is.

Comment: The order of the macro parameters might affect the result.

Comment: @Pete Becker &  Bo Persson, You are both correct, I missed that ! I reversed by mistake the parameters and I spend almost an hour trying to find out what seems to be wrong in the code....Maybe I am not too cautious at my age !